# MSP430 Stepper Motor

Tags: msp430, stepper-motor

I know that stepper motor structure is more different. I have MSP430 launchpad.
I know that I m guessing that I can't solder it to pins. Can I use it with breadboard, uln2003a and a potentiometer. This stuff is suitable with launchpad
I m going to use unipolar stepper motor.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't solder a motor directly to the output pins of a Launchpad.  You won't be able to source enough current for the stepper -- at least not any hobbyist stepper I've used before.  You can use it with a breadboard, but you won't be able to use the male header because the pins rows are spaced too far apart on the Launchpad to be used with a normal breadboard, unless you use *two* separate breadboards, one for each side of the Launchpad.

In my project, I'm using the female header option with jumper wires to hook up the Launchpad to peripherals.  So far it seems to work just fine.

The ULN2003A should work fine for now if you don't exceed its current rating, so check the datasheet.  I vaguely recall that it has provisions for external flyback diodes as well, and I feel you'll want to add those if possible.

Comment: I don't think that the ULN2003A is suitable for the MSP430 outputs, the voltage is too low.

Comment: @Leon Yikes, I should have looked at the datasheet.  I drove ULN2003As from an HC11, but of course that is a 5V chip.  Thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: People have run 2003 with a 430, at least at full 3.3 V. It might not have full current capacity, but will probably work. Other drivers might be better, though.